# How to run HelloWeb from asp.net vnext on a Mac?

Tags: linux, macos, asp.net-core

I watched the stream from TechEd 2014 for the Future of Asp .Net and I saw that they could run vnext projects in MAC. In the Github project doesn't say anything about this feature.

So My questions is how does someone goes about publishing and running the HelloWeb or HelloMVC samples on a MAC.

I noticed that Hanselman and David fowler were using a custom copy of Nowin names Nowin.K is this library going to be release as an example anywhere?

**UPDATE**

Currently what was shown on teched was a internal build put together show case the direction of the product. The team at microsoft together with the community are working hard to get the asp.net vnext working on linux and osx.

If you want to find out the current status check out on [Issue 173 on github.com/aspnet/kruntime](https://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/issues/173).

Once the support in integrated I will update this post and add answer explain how to go about it.

Regards

Comment: I'm trying to run them on Ubuntu, I believe we need to install the latest Mono. the kvm and kpm are all powershell scripts that execute programs in KRuntime project, for example Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager. We need to execute them manually or create our kvm, kpm scripts for OS X or Ubuntu.

Comment: Its possible to do away with the powershell scripts and just call the kruntime directly. hmm I am going to give it a try too see what I get.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Updated answer Jan 21 '15

There is now updated support for ASP.NET 5 on OS X and *nix. The best information is on the [ASP.NET Home Repo on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/home) that has a "Getting Started" section.

For OS X the Homebrew repo is here: https://github.com/aspnet/homebrew-k

For *nix the Docker repo is here: https://github.com/aspnet/aspnet-docker

### Original answer from May 24 '14

It seems that you've found the [discussion](https://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/issues/173) on the ASP.NET vNext "KRuntime" repo. Unfortunately the team is still in the midst of getting ASP.NET vNext working on Mac / Linux. What was shown at Tech Ed was live running code but using a lot of custom builds (e.g. Mono, as well as ASP.NET vNext). The team has been coordinating work with Miguel de Icaza to ensure that Mono has the required components for ASP.NET vNext. A lot of progress has been made, and it's getting very close, but it's not quite there.

Comment: Thank you eilon I will keep an eye on the discussion and update here when its working.

Comment: No longer the correct answer. vNext (KRE) is in Beta2. There are some glitches on LInux but it runs on Mac without problems.

Comment: @ppumkin thanks for the comment - I updated my answer to reflect the current state of things, please let me know if there's anything else I should update.

Answer (score 4):

## As of the year 2015, the the post below is outdated.

A post has come out: [ASP.NET vNext on OSX and Linux](http://graemechristie.github.io/graemechristie/blog/2014/05/26/asp-dot-net-vnext-on-osx-and-linux/)  I will give it a shot, see if I can run HelloMvc on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Any luck with it, i have tried it but no luck so far

Comment: @dmportella I believe you can make it by that post as well as its comments.

Comment: There are problems using kestrel (recommended over ASP Host on Linux) on Linux because of some missing libraries. I had to build `libuv` and then the SampleMVC worked! But, I went and did my OWN project in VS2015 and it complained it could not find `/../../../wwwroot` something strange with that. But its getting there. The blog post is outdated. No need to compile Mono any more but kestrel needs some adjustments which are not discussed in that link. Please update if you can.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you might be looking for is [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/). Described as:

> Cross platform, open source .NET framework
>
> Mono is an open source implementation of Microsoft's .NET Framework based on the ECMA standards for C# and the Common Language Runtime. A growing family of solutions and an active and enthusiastic contributing community is helping position Mono to become the leading choice for development of cross platform applications.